# PHP WooCommerce NEXT - PREVIOUS buttons for products in the same category - alignment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I used this code (below) it works great but the buttons NEXT and PREVIOUS are glued, I mean there is no space between them - is there a way to put PREVIOUS on the left side of the content and NEXT on the right? Image included - top one - current view, bottom one, as it should be [IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZleLz.jpg)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'bbloomer_prev_next_product' );


function bbloomer_prev_next_product(){

echo '<div class="prev_next_buttons">';
    
   // 'product_cat' will make sure to return next/prev from current category
        $previous = next_post_link('%link', '&larr; PREVIOUS', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');
        $next = previous_post_link('%link', 'NEXT &rarr;', TRUE,' ', 'product_cat');

    echo $previous;
    echo $next;

echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: Another question for that php code - it works great but I'm wondering how to loop it... so the Previous Next buttons show up always (right now on the first product there is no 'previous' and on the last there is no 'next') - anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'bbloomer_prev_next_product' );


function bbloomer_prev_next_product(){

echo '<div class="prev_next_buttons">';
    
   // 'product_cat' will make sure to return next/prev from current category
       next_post_link('<p style="float:left;">%link</p>', '&larr; PREVIOUS', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');
       previous_post_link('<p style="float:right;">%link</p>', 'NEXT &rarr;', TRUE,' ', 'product_cat');


echo '</div>';

}
```